# What SFPs can be used with Dell MD36x0f storage?

Tags: dell, fiber, fibre-channel, sfp, dell-powervault

I've not found any information about used SFPs and supported cable length (which is what I actually want to know). [Online configuration wizard](http://configure.us.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?oc=brcthb3&c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&model_id=powervault-md36x0f-series) does not allow to choose SFP type, only quantity. One presentation that I have states that maximum cable length is 10km, but I unable to find any confirmations in specs. "10km" only specified as recommended distance for synchronous replication. So, what SFPs can be used and what is maximum cable length supported by MD36x0f?

Comment: There's an easy way to get these answers... call Dell and ask them. I'm not being flippant here, if it were me and I had these questions, I would put them to a Dell rep.

Answer (score 1):

Are these SFP modules with fiber optics between or copper SFP to SFP cables?

If it is fiber optics then if you are using:

- Multimode = About 1,500 FT
- Singlemode = About 3 - 5 Miles

Answer (score 0):

SFP is a socket standard ('Small Form-factor Plugin') for various modules that interface different types of F/C connectors.  Common ones are:

- Multi-mode fibre (orange cables).  This will go a few hundred metres and is the most common type you will see in a data centre.
- Single-mode fibre (yellow cables).  This will go several kilometres and has a substantially more powerful laser.  Even though they use invisible near-IR frequencies the eye will still focus them and they represent a laser hazard.  This type of cable is also common on inbound links from the Telco.
- HSSDC/HSSDC2.  These are copper and good for about 20-30m IIRC.  I have also seen HSSDC-SFP cables where the cable is directly wired into a SFP connector.

Chances are you want multi-mode (SC-SC) connectors - orange fibre, or copper.  Ask your vendor about the connectors.